# BInding for Listbox In WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a Main window with textbox. I enter some text and  click enter it popups a window with listbox and displays the items matching the text entered in the Mainwindow. On selecting the item from the ListBox the text gets set in my textbox of Mainwindow.

I am following the MVVM Pattern. I am not able to set the binding for my listbox in my Mainwindow.(Using CommandBinding)

Does anyone has some solution or sample for the similar scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the ViewModel you need a property `SelectedListBoxItem`

Bind it to the `SelectedItem` of your ListBox.

Bind the Text-property to the `SelectedListBoxItem` of your ViewModel

and that should basically be it.

```
<ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}"    
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedListBoxItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
        />

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedListBoxItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
        />
```

Comment: I was trying the something similar but it didn't worked for me. 
Can u Please paste the sample code.?